# Angular year picker with future year disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

[image] I want to show a year picker with future years disabled

this is the code i am using,  please help me

viewData.formDateOptionsyear = {
formatYear: 'yyyy',
startingDay: 1,
minMode: 'year',
date:new Date().getFullYear(),

};

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy" ng-model="rel.year"  ng-disabled="rel.id" is-open="data1.isOpen" datepicker-options="viewData.formDateOptionsyear" show-button-bar="false" />
```

Comment: maybe using the property `maxDate` : "Defines the maximum available date. Requires a Javascript Date object."

Comment: @ Cédric MEYER i tried with maxDate it didn't work      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy" 
                     ng-model="rel.year"  ng-disabled="rel.id" is-open="data1.isOpen" datepicker-options="viewData.formDateOptionsyear"
                     show-button-bar="false" max-date="viewData.formDateOptionsyear.maxDate" />                                                                                      
viewData.formDateOptionsyear = { formatYear: 'yyyy',startingDay: 1,minMode: 'year', maxDate:new Date().getFullYear(),
    
  };